# Nginx: add_header section when using embedded locations

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx configuration where there are many `location` sections withing `location /`. This is because we set various caching strategies for other type of content etc.

However, now I've needed a common http header (`Content-Security-Policy`), so I've added it into root location. But it's applied only for not listed resources (in my case, `favicon.ico`).

Do I really need to copy my header to all nested locations, or it is possible to define common configuration for the whole section?

This is my config:

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self';";
    location ~* \.htm(l?) {

    }
    location ~* \.js {
        add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=86400';
    }
    location ~* \.css {
        ...
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|svg|png) {
        add_header Cache-Control 'max-age=43200';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless there is an `add_header` statement within the nested location, the `add_header` directives from the surrounding block will be inherited.

Comment: @RichardSmith I've got add_header directive, but for other header....

Comment: An `add_header` statement for **any header** will prevent the `add_header` statements from the outer block from being inherited. It's [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header).

Comment: @RichardSmith so this is the answer. Anyway, It seems I don't need Content-Security-Policy on anything else then html pages.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a `map`, something like the following:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    application/javascript  86400;
    default                 off;
    ~image/                 43200;
}
```

which then allows you to reduce the configuration to:

```
expires $expires;
```

in your top-level location, getting rid of the individual `add_header Cache-Control ...` directives, and at the same time being then able to add the `add_header Content-Security-Policy ...` directive.